# When is the construction "I myself" suitable?

Tags: personal-pronouns, emphasis

A previous question, [*How to call attention to "I" without "I myself" or the pretentious "Even I"?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21786/how-to-call-attention-to-i-without-i-myself-or-the-pretentious-even-i), suggested that the *"I myself"* construction is often used for emphasis, with one answer correctly pointing out that it is grammatically correct.

I find this completely redundant. When is it suitable to use "I myself"?

Comment: Is the second 'o' in "Loose" redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *myself* in "I myself" is called an intensive pronoun.  It is used to ascribe significance to the preceding noun or pronoun.

> In fact, I myself have gone through the caves.

Comment: I see. So it's simply the placement of the intensive pronoun that I find awkward, then. (As I would write that sentence as "In fact, I have gone through the caves myself.")

Comment: @Lloyd: Yes.  That is another valid way to place the intensive.  The nuances in meaning are subtly changed, though.